# ignore AssertFailException under WP7

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I am unit-testing my windows phone 7 app. I' using the Framework, that is provided via the Windows Phone Test-Project Template in Visual Studi.

I'm getting AssertFailExceptions, and the Debugger starts, because some UnitTests don't work properly. But I want, the test-driver to continue, without throwing exceptions.

I already tried to disable the halt for the errors (http://www.benday.com/2010/08/18/silverlight-unit-tests-how-to-stop-breaking-on-assert-exceptions/) and this: http://sgomez.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-disable-assert-dialogs-while.html

Thanks!